# TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to dump a bunch of `dicts` to an `.xlsx` file by means of the following lines:

```
H=0.5 #Used to name the xlsx file
fail_thre=0.2 #Used to name the xlsx file
dict_list=[dict1,dict2,dict3] #The list of dictionaries to be dumped
myindex=['event 1','event 2','event 3'] #Used to name rows
from itertools import izip_longest
stats_matrix=[ tuple('dict{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(dict_list))) ] + list( izip_longest(*([ v for k,v in sorted(d.items())] for d in dict_list)) )
import pandas as pd
column_names=['Dict1','Dict2','Dict3']
mydf=pd.DataFrame(stats_matrix,index=myindex,columns=column_names) #Creating a data frame for MS Excel visualization
mydf.columns = ['Dict1','Dict2','Dict3']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Lattice_stats_H_'+str(Hurst)+'FAIL_'+str(fail_thre)+'_FLOODING.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Lattice')   
writer.save()
```

But I get this error (please note that the names in `column_names` and `mydf.columns` and etc. are the real names of my dicts, which are too long to be posted):

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\Scripts\Network_Scripts\Lattice_ForLoop_FLOODING.py in <module>()
    399 mydf.columns = ['failed_nodes_1Stage','percent_failed_haz','act_nodes_1Stage','percent_active_haz','failed_nodes_2Stage','percent_failed_conn','failed_nodes_1plus2','percent_failed_1plus2','act_nodes_2Stage','percent_active_conn','total_failed_nodes','percent_total_failed_nodes','total_active_nodes','percent_total_active_nodes','giant_component','center_giant_comp','network_diam','connectedness','average_degree', 'graph_len']
    400 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Lattice_stats_H_'+str(Hurst)+'FAIL_'+str(fail_thre)+'_FLOODING.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
--> 401 mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Lattice')
    402 writer.save()
    403 

C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep)
   1272         formatted_cells = formatter.get_formatted_cells()
   1273         excel_writer.write_cells(formatted_cells, sheet_name,
-> 1274                                  startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
   1275         if need_save:
   1276             excel_writer.save()

C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol)
   1337                 wks.write(startrow + cell.row,
   1338                           startcol + cell.col,
-> 1339                           cell.val, style)
   1340 
   1341     def _convert_to_style(self, style_dict, num_format_str=None):

C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.pyc in cell_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     62             args = new_args
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     65 
     66     return cell_wrapper

C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.pyc in write(self, row, col, *args)
    429             pass
    430         except TypeError:
--> 431             raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
    432 
    433         # Finally try string.

TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mydf` dataframe has elements of type `list` in the dataframe cells.  It is likely due to how you built `stats_matrix`.  See the [the pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/dsintro.html#dataframe) for the appropriate ways to call DataFrame.  To find your problems, you could call `mydf.applymap(type)` and see where the lists reside in `mydf`.

If you wanted to translate those list items into strings without the braces/brackets, you could use this function to convert the culprit column into a column that would work:

```
def list_to_number_string(value):
    if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        return str(value)[1:-1]
    else:
        return value

mydf[badcol] = mydf[badcol].apply(list_to_number_string)
```

Comment: Found it. There is a column which bears `list` type. And, unfortunately, I really need that column to be like that. Is there any workaround? The values of that column are meant to be something like: `17,56,89,212,567,789`. That is, a list of integers.

Comment: Added a function for you to clean it the problem cells.

Comment: The line `mydf[center_giant_comp] = mydf[center_giant_comp].apply(list_to_number_string)` throws out an error since the dicts to be written are `OrderedDicts` in reality. What should I change in your function to account for this?

Comment: It depends on what the OrderDict contents look like and what you want it to look like in your excel cells.  If you share that information, would be an easy add to the function.

Comment: This is what the ordered dict looks like before entering the suggested function: `center_giant_comp={'event 1':[12,45,78,123],'event 2':[67,89,345,678],'event 3':[346,678],...,'event n':[num1,num2,num3...]}`. The number of values in each list is either 0 or an even number, and they are always integer.

Comment: It might be faster if you edit the question with exactly how you want the excel spreadsheet to look  (what are the columns, what are the rows, what does an intended sample of it look like).  That way, I can suggest a better way to represent the data in the data frame and then the output to excel is trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95741/discussion-between-davidshinn-and-francesco-castellani).